# PHP shared memory - перезапись c изменением размера, или аналог realloc

Tags: php, memory

В блоке общей памяти должна постоянно обновляться информация, которая приходит часто (15 - 25 раз в секунду). Размеры каждой "порции" отличаются, и при чтении желательно иметь точный размер записанных в данный момент данных. При `shmop_write`, если новые данные короче старых, они будут записаны с нулевого смещения, а сзади остаётся "хвост" от старых.

**Можно ли как-то менять размер блока памяти без его постоянного создания/удаления при каждом поступлении данных?** По типу realloc из C, чтобы "хвостов" не оставалось?

Comment: просто предваряйте данные числом с их длиной или делайте паддинг

Comment: 15-25 раз в секунду, это ерунда. Любой memcached, redis справиться. Зато можно будет и читать и писать любим языком из любого места. Просто немного не понятна задача и выбор инструмента.

Comment: Плюс у PHP есть набор структур, которые "ближе к железу"  http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php.

Comment: Задача - по одному и тому же адресу памяти записывать данные так, чтобы если длина новой строки меньше того, что уже записано по этому адресу, у новой строки не оставалось "хвоста" от старой. И всё ) То есть обновлять размер выделенной памяти. @etki, с паддингом не понял - как он уменьшит буфер?

Comment: Да не вытащите вы из местных пользователей волшебный интерфейс, если он отсутствует в документации. Если у вас будет паддинг байтами, которые не могут встретится в строке, то в этом случае просто отрезаете все лишнее справа и даже не волнуетесь за то, какой там размер.

Comment: Вы описываете не задачу а решение. Если вам нужен интерфейс между 2мя приложениями то лучше посмотрите на redis, memcached. Даже те же `sockets(unix/tcp/udp)`... или база данных(SQLite).

Comment: Памятью управляет index.php - типа псевдо-сервер. Клиент №1 отдаёт base64 картинку. Клиент №2 её читает, не имея понятия о том какого она размера, но в его img src должно быть именно то, что №1 отправил в последний раз. @E_p, я хотел сделать на сокетах, но сказали - нет, надо скрипт ))

Comment: `base64` это 30% дополнительного места. Почему нельзя просто в файловой системе хронить? Можно даже сделать `mount`  памяти `memdrive` если это unix система. А есть ограничения на размер файла? Файл всегда 1?

Comment: @etki, я понял идею. Просто перед data:image пишу реальный размер, а при чтении извлекаю intval из подстроки до "data:", и отправляю "читателю" подстроку с "data:..." нужного размера. Это конечно дополнительные вычислительные затраты, но должно работать! Спасибо за идею, сразу не понял )

Comment: А по сути вы переписываете `memcached` только на PHP. А что будет если памяти не хватит?

Comment: @E_p, Думаю, 1,2 МБ сервер найдёт - по 12 кб на каждого (столько максимум весит base64-jpeg с 75% сжатием 320х240), а больше 100 клиентов вряд ли наберётся )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то типа такого:

```
<?php

class MemoryManager
{
    public function __construct($maxSize, $maxClients)
    {

        // Validation
        $shm_key = ftok(__FILE__, 't'); 
        $this->_memoryPointer = shmop_open($shm_key, "c", 0644, $maxSize * $maxClients);
        $this->_maxSize = $maxSize;
        $this->_maxClient = $maxSize;
    }

    public function writeClientData($clientId, $data)
    {
        $paddedData = str_pad($data, $this->_maxSize, $this->_padSymbol);
        shmop_write(
            $this->_memoryPointer,
            $paddedData,
            ($clientId - 1) * $this->_maxSize
        );
    }

    public function readClientData($clientId)
    {
        $data = shmop_read(
            $this->_memoryPointer,
            ($clientId - 1) * $this->_maxSize,
            $this->_maxSize
        );

        return trim($data, $this->_padSymbol);
    }

    public function readAll()
    {
        $data = shmop_read(
            $this->_memoryPointer,
            0,
            $this->_maxSize*$this->_maxClient
        );

        $string = preg_replace(
            sprintf("/(\%s+)/", $this->_padSymbol),
            $this->_padSymbol,
            trim($data, "\000" . $this->_padSymbol)
        );

        return explode($this->_padSymbol, $string);
    }


    public function close()
    {
        shmop_delete($this->_memoryPointer);
        shmop_close($this->_memoryPointer);
    }


    private $_padSymbol = "|";
}


$mem = new MemoryManager(100, 100);

$mem->writeClientData(1, 'aaaaa');
$mem->writeClientData(2, 'bbbbbbbb');
var_dump($mem->readClientData(1));
var_dump($mem->readClientData(2));


$mem->writeClientData(2, 'cc');
var_dump($mem->readClientData(2));

var_dump($mem->readAll());

$mem->close();
```

Comment: Там валидация пропущена повсюду. И может есть смысл поменять `|` на другой симбвол, ну не суть.

Comment: И Вы натолкнули на мысль! ) Если задать фиксированный буфер, например 20 кб, вновь пришедшему изображению сделать str_pad до нужной длины (то есть забить пробелами оставшийся буфер), и вернуть trim-строку - тоже класс! А что быстрее отработает, этот вариант, или парсинг подстрок на значения длины? Похоже, что первый, да?

Comment: @Iceman Да всеравно, можно потестировать. Мне кажеться там другие проблемы будыт, чем эта пара милисекунд.

Comment: Ну я сейчас тестировал с парсингом подстрок - работает как надо, правда на потоке не проверял ещё. Но эти пара милисекунд очень влияют, так как на клиенте надо это изображение сформировать, передать на сервер, другой клиент его должен забрать, а это тоже задержки, а видео должно идти плавно ). В любом случае, спасибо за наводку, +1!

Comment: #Iceman Попробуйте. Отпишитесь. Даже интересно какой результат будет.

Comment: Хорошо! Думаю в любом случае будет побыстрее ramdisk'а

Comment: @Iceman Почитал ваши вапросы, вам может так же быть интересно:

http://reactphp.org/
http://socketo.me/


https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop
https://github.com/reactphp/http

Comment: Всё работает отлично с str_pad / trim - поток плавный

Comment: @Iceman Отлично. Можно побаловаться со строковыми функциями, повыжимать еще скорость, но если работает, то всё ок. Если PHP сервер гонять как демона(постоянно в памяти) и использовать `SplFixedArray` как хранилище, то у меня получилось увеличить скорость запись/чтение в 40 раз(не надо строки `pad`, `trim` делать) ну и памяти он в 2 раза меньше кушал. Но тогда будет проблема, демона живым держать...